# React doesn't show images or svg files

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, svg

My problem is that react doesn't show any image (jpeg, png) or svg file. I've been trying some different techniques such as a simple import inside src attribute of an image, or using `require()`. But I couldn't solve the problem, I also tried to move the image between the different folders and that also doesn't work.
I´m using react and styled-components, here is some of my code:

```
<Img src={require('../../images/cuervo.png')} alt={alt}></Img>
```

Creating a new compponent:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Icon } from '@material-ui/core'

const mainLogo = require("./logo.svg")
const Logo = () => {
    return (
        <Icon>
            <img src={ mainLogo } height={25} width = {25}>
            </img>
        </Icon>
    )
}

export default Logo
```

Import does not work, either.

Comment: Hey Mark, could you please add a bit more context? For instance, if you try doing "inspect element" in your browser, does it show an error on the console? What is the `src` attribute of the image in the HTML code?

Comment: the inspect show as: `<img src="[object Module]" height="25" width="25">` . trying to give them a bit more of context. the image is a SVG file, I want to show the svg inside a navbar. in the console just show two warnings about img alt atribute and the other one is about a component that is never used

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try replacing the Icon tag with just a figure tag, as shown below, and let me know if that works. It could be that the Icon tag is being annoying.

```
import React from 'react'
import mainLogo from 'location/of/your/image'

const Logo = () => {
    return (
        <figure>
            <img src={ mainLogo } alt="Logo" />
        </figure>
    )
}

export default Logo
```

Also, I'm sure you're importing the Logo component correctly into the main component where you want this Logo to be shown, but maybe double-check that to see if it's being imported correctly :)

Comment: I think that the import isn´t the problem, my svg file is inside the same folder, and when the app is running it´s show on inspect section of google chrome as `<figure><img src="[object Module]" alt="Logo"></figure>`